PDF Issues on Samsung S21 Ultra
Have a Samsung S21 Ultra, I am doing an online course that requires to see material in PDF format.  Every time I hit on view course it just flashes, and then nothing.  I have tried to download pdf on app store none work.  Is it possible that I have something turned off or not set right on my phone that keeps me from seeing these pdf files.  My DELL Laptop is working fine with getting pdf from this site.

Which PDF viewer apps have you tried?

Adobe Acrobat and PDF Reader for android. Either I picked wrong apps, didn't set them up properly or something on my phone isn't setup properly.

This is because you have previously selected some app to view pdfs all the time. Downloading new apps is not enough.

Go to Settings
Select Apps
Select Choose Default Apps
Scroll and see if there is an app for pdf viewing or document viewing or any such phrase
Press on it
Select a new default app.

